# How to prevent Bootstrap columns jump from one part to the other or under each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a testimonial part for my project. There are 4 divs, but their content is uneven, therefore when I start to pull the width of the screen together, in `col-sm-6`they're supposed to line up like 2-2, but the div no.3 jumps over to the place of div no.4, leaving an empty space behind, then the div no.4 jumps a row below. How can I prevent them of messing up? I've tried adding `max-width`, but that didn't work either...

```css
.testimonial-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
}
.testimonial-content h5 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.testim-logo-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.testimonial-logo {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="testimonial-content">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="testim-logo-container">
        <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/999/000/?text=1" alt="testimonial logo">
      </div>
      <p>"It's amazing to see the progress of the students, that Laszlo and Balazs has been going through during the Multimedia Design education at the IBA."</p>
      <h5>Tina Østergaard Filsø</h5>
      <h5>Visual Communication - IBA</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-content">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="testim-logo-container">
        <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/6c9/000/?text=2" alt="testimonial logo">
      </div>
      <p>"Laszlo showed dedication and self discipline during his period with Our Daily Heroes."</p>
      <h5>Gyula Vajda</h5>
      <h5>CEO - Our Daily Heroes</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-content">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="testim-logo-container">
        <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/c96/000/?text=3" alt="testimonial logo">
      </div>
      <p>"It was great to work with Balazs, easy going, enthusiastic, works fast and on a reasonable price."</p>
      <h5>Dániel Szilágyi</h5>
      <h5>Founder - BudapestDenTrip</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="testimonial-content">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="testim-logo-container">
        <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/96c/000/?text=4" alt="testimonial logo">
      </div>
      <p>"Laszlo was a top-A intern, he took the assignments very seriously and executed them well.<br />He is enthusiastic to learn and experience new things."</p>
      <h5>Björgvin Pétur</h5>
      <h5>Senior Designer - //JÖKULÁ</h5>
    </div>
  </div><!-- Testimonials end-->
</div><!-- Testimonials row ends-->
```

Comment: give fixed height to the columns, probably the simplest method to solve the issue.

Comment: For some reason if I give them a fixed height, they jump into a single columns below each other, but when I try to add the a fixed width, then the total width of all 4 columns gets for ex. 300px. I couldn't spot any unclosed div tags or wrapper having the same name though...

Comment: In the meantime I've figured out, that the `col-lg, sm, xs` attribute classes were wrapped into the `.testimonial-content`, therefore a fixed size set for it applied for all for in total. After I've changed these two, so the `.testimonial-content` is inside the col-classes, the settings given work fine for each of them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using `flexbox` you can avoid the issue. You gotta modify your markup a bit. Please check the code snipped attached

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.testimonial-content {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
}

.testimonial-content h5 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.testim-logo-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.testimonial-logo {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row flex-row">
    <div class="testimonial-content col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="testim-logo-container">
            <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/999/000/?text=1"
                alt="testimonial logo">
        </div>
        <p>"It's amazing to see the progress of the students, that Laszlo and Balazs has been going through during
            the Multimedia Design education at the IBA."</p>
        <h5>Tina Østergaard Filsø</h5>
        <h5>Visual Communication - IBA</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-content col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="testim-logo-container">
            <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/6c9/000/?text=2"
                alt="testimonial logo">
        </div>
        <p>"Laszlo showed dedication and self discipline during his period with Our Daily Heroes."</p>
        <h5>Gyula Vajda</h5>
        <h5>CEO - Our Daily Heroes</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-content col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="testim-logo-container">
            <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/c96/000/?text=3"
                alt="testimonial logo">
        </div>
        <p>"It was great to work with Balazs, easy going, enthusiastic, works fast and on a reasonable price."</p>
        <h5>Dániel Szilágyi</h5>
        <h5>Founder - BudapestDenTrip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-content col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="testim-logo-container">
            <img class="img-responsive testimonial-logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50/96c/000/?text=4"
                alt="testimonial logo">
        </div>
        <p>"Laszlo was a top-A intern, he took the assignments very seriously and executed them well.<br />He is
            enthusiastic to learn and experience new things."</p>
        <h5>Björgvin Pétur</h5>
        <h5>Senior Designer - //JÖKULÁ</h5>
    </div><!-- Testimonials end-->
</div><!-- Testimonials row ends-->
```

> Old answer [Outdated - JS solution]

You gotta give fixed `height` for the boxes. Since its height may vary with `text`, alignment issue will occur.

for eg:

```
.col-lg-6{
 height: 500px;
}
```

A common and quick way to solve this problem is use equal-height using `JavaScript`.

https://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

```
equalheight = function(container) {

    var currentTallest = 0,
        currentRowStart = 0,
        rowDivs = new Array(),
        $el,
        topPosition = 0;
    $(container).each(function() {

        $el = $(this);
        $($el).height('auto')
        topPostion = $el.position().top;

        if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
            for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
                rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
            }
            rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
            currentRowStart = topPostion;
            currentTallest = $el.height();
            rowDivs.push($el);
        } else {
            rowDivs.push($el);
            currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
        }
        for (currentDiv = 0; currentDiv < rowDivs.length; currentDiv++) {
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
        }
    });
}
$(window).resize(function() {   //to work in resize
    equalheight('.col-lg-6');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 equalheight('.col-lg-6');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap's `col` are floating on the left, so if they don't have the same height, you'll end up like that.

The 2 solution would be :

- setting a height to all the columns
- adding a `clearfix` to the third column on small screen.

Comment: For some reason if I give them a fixed height, they jump into a single columns below each other, but when I try to add the a fixed width, then the total width of all 4 columns gets for ex. 300px. I couldn't spot any unclosed div tags or wrapper having the same name though... Btw, how do you add clearfix only to small screen? Does any HTML solution exist for it, or just the css code of clearfix in a media query?

Comment: In the meantime I've figured out, that the `col-lg, sm, xs` attribute classes were wrapped into the `.testimonial-content`, therefore a fixed size set for it applied for all for in total. After I've changed these two, so the `.testimonial-content` is inside the col-classes, the settings given work fine for each of them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your columns like this (I added two more rows inside the main row which clears floats on "sm" and "md" screens):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!-- col 1 content -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!-- col 2 content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!-- col 3 content -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <!-- col 4 content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have just tried this method, sounds logic but the result I got is 4 very thin and long columns... :-/

Comment: In the meantime I've figured out, that the `col-lg, sm, xs` attribute classes were wrapped into the `.testimonial-content`, therefore a fixed size set for it applied for all for in total. After I've changed these two, so the `.testimonial-content` is inside the col-classes, the settings given work fine for each of them separately.