# Mysql data not arranged in perfect row

Tags: html, css, row

Thanks for previous helps. Am here with another one.

Ok, so i am retrieving data from database.. its working fine, but where i have issues is that after the data spans the first row it doesn't start from the first column of the next row.. I don't know how to explain this better ... but I'I'll add the code and image here....

```
<div class="row">
                     <?php

                                        $selectCat = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cat_id DESC";
                                        $selectCatKwary = mysqli_query($link, $selectCat);
                                        $catCount = mysqli_num_rows($selectCatKwary);
                                        if ($catCount > 0) {

                                        ?>

                                        <?php
                                        while ( $catRow = mysqli_fetch_array($selectCatKwary)) { ?>

                    <a href="">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="row">


                                        <div class="col-xs-5">
                                            <div class="icon-big icon-warning text-center">
                                                <i class="ti-user"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                                            <div class="numbers">
                                                <p class="text-uppercase text-bold"><?php echo $catRow['catTitle']; ?></p>
                                                105GB
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <?php  } } ?>
                </div>
```

and here is the image

[image: image of how it shows]

The first four data resolved well... the next one which MOBILE CARS did not start from the beginning column, and also affected others

Comment: this is neither a php nor a mysqli question.

Comment: Hmm..... It is.... Cuz wen I try to start my WHILE LOOP before the <div class="row">.... It displays them as list.... I did like to display them in grid

Comment: I'm assuming it is because your columns aren't the same height, e.g. "COMPUTER GAMES" moving onto the next line. Checkout this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460834/how-to-prevent-bootstrap-columns-jump-from-one-part-to-the-other-or-under-each-o

Comment: @YvesLeBorg is correct, this is CSS issue and not understanding how floats work. _Mobile Cars_ is _"snagging"_ on _Computer Games. Though I would try to not use the solution in the link above, it uses fixed heights. If you were using Bootstrap 4, your columns would be equal height by default.

Comment: @hungerstar.. so do you suggest I just change from bootstrap 3 to 4

Comment: Possibly. If you are just starting your project and do not have too much time invested, then switching might be worthwhile. Otherwise, you might want to look at a solution like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height#answer-22892773